# Xamarin.UWP Runtime error in Release mode

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin.forms, uwp

I get an error when running my Xamarin.Forms.UWP app in Release Mode.

```
onecore\com\combase\inc\comcataloghelpers.hpp(64)\combase.dll!00007FFD5E991DAA: (caller: 00007FFD5E990205) ReturnHr(1) tid(6adc) 80040154 Klasse nicht registriert
onecore\com\combase\inc\comcataloghelpers.hpp(64)\combase.dll!00007FFD5E991DAA: (caller: 00007FFD5E990205) ReturnHr(2) tid(2ac4) 80040154 Klasse nicht registriert
onecore\com\combase\inc\comcataloghelpers.hpp(64)\combase.dll!00007FFD5E991DAA: (caller: 00007FFD5E990205) ReturnHr(3) tid(39ec) 80040154 Klasse nicht registriert
onecore\com\combase\inc\comcataloghelpers.hpp(64)\combase.dll!00007FFD5E991DAA: (caller: 00007FFD5E990205) ReturnHr(4) tid(27a4) 80040154 Klasse nicht registriert
Exception thrown: 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' in System.Private.Reflection.Core.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' in System.Private.Reflection.Core.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' in System.Private.Reflection.Core.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' in System.Private.Reflection.Core.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' in System.Private.Reflection.Core.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' in System.Private.Reflection.Core.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.PlatformNotSupportedException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.PlatformNotSupportedException' in System.Private.Interop.dll
Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFD43DB83B9 (Windows.UI.Xaml.dll) in Lama.Forms.UWP.exe: 0xC000027B: Anwendungsinterne Ausnahme (parameters: 0x000001FF87EB6FA0, 0x0000000000000002).
```

This happens inside the automatic generated code-section inside *App.xaml.cs*

```
protected override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs e)
        {
            Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;

            // Do not repeat app initialization when the Window already has content,
            // just ensure that the window is active
            if (rootFrame == null)
            {
                // Create a Frame to act as the navigation context and navigate to the first page
                rootFrame = new Frame();

                rootFrame.NavigationFailed += OnNavigationFailed;

                Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(e);

                if (e.PreviousExecutionState == ApplicationExecutionState.Terminated)
                {
                    //TODO: Load state from previously suspended application
                }

                // Place the frame in the current Window
                Window.Current.Content = rootFrame;
            }

            if (rootFrame.Content == null)
            {
                // When the navigation stack isn't restored navigate to the first page,
                // configuring the new page by passing required information as a navigation
                // parameter
                rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage), e.Arguments);
            }
```

Inside this line:

```
rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage), e.Arguments);
```

This only happens if I run the app in *Release* mode, if I do in *Debug*, there is no error happening.

Comment: do you use any third party component in your project?

Comment: Yes I am using multiple ones.```DLToolkit.Forms.Controls.FlowListView```, ```Microsoft.AppCenter.*```, ```SkiaSharp```, ```Com.Airbnb.Xamarin.Forms.Lottie```, ```Xamanimation``` and many more

Comment: Then you have to be sure that all of your third party can support the .NET Target framework you are going to use on your xamarin.forms project. Otherwise, wrong assembly resolution may occur, and that exception is one of the example.

Comment: But this must then be happening in debug mode also, which doesn't

Comment: There is a difference in debug and release mode. In release mode, all of the resulting assemblies of DLLs might get mixed. Especially if one of your third party has dependency to legacy portable class libraries. Please read official MS Docs on .NET TFM, and also this article: https://oren.codes/2017/04/23/using-xamarin-forms-with-net-standard-vs-2017-edition/

Comment: Your provided article handles the convertion from PCL to .netStandard CL but I don't run/reference any PCL, nor do I think any dependency does.

Answer (score 0):

In Release Mode, you have do [load Assemblies on your own](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/xamarin/xamarin-forms/platform/windows/installation/#troubleshooting):

```
// You'll need to add using System.Reflection;

List<Assembly> assembliesToInclude = new List<Assembly>();

// Now, add in all the assemblies your app uses
assembliesToInclude.Add(typeof (ClassInOtherAssembly).GetTypeInfo().Assembly);

// Also do this for all your other 3rd party libraries
Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(e, assembliesToInclude);
// replaces Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(e);
```

So add every 3rd party class you use 1 line `assembliesToInclude.Add(typeof (ClassInOtherAssembly).GetTypeInfo().Assembly);`

Comment: So I did exactly what the docs mentioned to do and referenced every third party library and also mines, and I still get the same error

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by unchecking "Compile with .NET Native tool chain" inside my UWP project. But I am not sure if this is only a temporary fix

Comment: this was also posted in the link I posted ("This might occur when using the Compile with .NET Native tool chain which is an option for UWP apps in the Properties > Build > General window for the project.") and the extra code should fix this. Confusing.